# My Macbook Pro crashes every time I change my desktop

Tags: crash

So everytime I change my background on my desktop, I go and delete the image. The next thing I almost always find is that the next time I turn my Macbook on, the whole thing freezes and I always have to safe boot my laptop.

Once I do manage to boot up again, my original background completely disappears and my desktop goes back to the "universe" background

I am getting frustrated with this. I don't know why deleting an image will cause my laptop to do this sort of thing. My Macbook isn't even a year old.

I have OS X 10.8.2

**EDIT** I just restarted my laptop and now it's even worst. It's quite laggy and my whole wallpaper is now just completely blank white.

Comment: In case this isn't just a bug, have you backed up everything and then tried booting to the recovery HD to run disk utility and verify the drive catalog and data structures are all OK?

Comment: Sorry could you dumb that down for me? Not a total expert in computers...

Answer (score 1):

If your Mac still works, I would connect a USB drive (or other) and make sure [Time Machine](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1427) gets a full backup before anything else goes wrong.

At that point with your files safe, you can use [OS X Recovery](http://www.apple.com/osx/recovery/) to [run Disk Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1417). The first link has some very general items in case this is the first time you've heard of Recovery or Disk Utility.

As you troubleshoot this, you can either ask a follow on question or edit the question if you can rule out some things you have tried or need more specific help using / deciding which step of these tools and guides to take next.

Comment: I am not trying to "recover" what went wrong, I am trying to find a solution so this won't even happen again

Comment: OK - I'm just offering the best advice I have to solve the problem of missing wall paper and slowness. Of the 20 times I've seen it - it's always been disk corruption since the plist for this is pretty robust and hard to mess up. I could be wrong - so feel free to follow the other advice that shows up here. Commenting that it wasn't helpful is always good so that others can see and either reinforce my take on it or provide another solution.